# Using a WHERE with a UNION'ed view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, union, where-clause

I have a view in MySQL which is comprised of 2 **SELECT** queries **UNION**'ed together (both queries draw from the same table, but aggregate different data - therefore the columns match in both).

I have a weird issue where if I query this view and add a **WHERE** clause, rows disappear that should be listed. If I take the code that makes the view (ie. the 2 selects that union together) and add the various WHERE's to each, the query works fine.

So, my question is, does a WHERE clause in this situation only apply to the first group of rows returned within the view, before the UNION takes place? If so, is there something I can change in my view to allow the WHERE to propagate to both selects?

Comment: try to put WHERE after last SELECT

Comment: That does work if I'm running the queries separately, but my two queries are UNION'ed in a view **before** I add the WHERE clause. Therefore, it seems the WHERE is only applying to the first SELECT in the VIEW